# Howto change a theme using PHP when all separate theme colors are defined as PHP variables in a file?

Tags: php, variables, frameworks, themes

I have created an own PHP framework for building websites. I start out to define some basic variables in a file called "definitions.php". Amongst other configurations therein, I also have defined color schemes through PHP variables which are being used in the other PHP files which load "definition.php (e. g. in '').

**definitions.php:**

```
    <?php
    [lots of variable-based definitions not interesting here]

    // Color Composition 02 (#F0F8FF - AliceBlue)
    /*
    $DARK_MODE             = 0;
    $SECURITY_MODE         = 'multi';
    $DATE_COLOR            = '#FFD700';
    $RESP_COLOR            = '#FFD700';
    $TD_COLOR_LEFT         = '#F0F8FF';
    $TD_COLOR_RIGHT        = '#F0F8FF';
    $TR_COLOR_RIGHT        = '#F0F8FF';
    $TR_COLOR_RIGHT_02     = '#F0F8FF';
    $TD_COLOR_INSIDE_EMPTY = '#F0F8FF';
    $BORDER_TABLE          = '0px';
    $DATA_COLOR            = '#F0F8FF';
    $FOREGR_COLOR          = 'lightgray';
    $REV_COLOR             = 'lightgreen';
    $OBLIG_COLOR           = 'lightblue';
    $INPUT_BG_COLOR        = 'lightgray';
    $INPUT_COLOR           = 'blue';
    $INPUT_WEIGHT          = 'normal'; // 'bold';
    $MENU_SURROUND_COLOR   = '#302D26';
    $SPINNER_COLOR         = '#4D4B48';
    $HR_COLOR              = 'darkgray';
    $BODY_MARGIN_TOP       = '5px';
    */

    // Color Composition 03 (#F0F8FF - Night Mode / Dark Mode)
    $DARK_MODE             = 1;
    $SECURITY_MODE         = 'single';
    $DATE_COLOR            = '#4D4B48';
    $RESP_COLOR            = '#4D4B48';
    $TD_COLOR_LEFT         = '#4D4B48';
    $TD_COLOR_RIGHT        = '#302D26';
    $TR_COLOR_RIGHT        = '#302D26';
    $TR_COLOR_RIGHT_02     = '#F0F8FF';
    $TD_COLOR_INSIDE_EMPTY = '#4D4B48';
    $BORDER_TABLE          = '0px';
    $DATA_COLOR            = '#4D4B48'; // '#302D26';
    $FOREGR_COLOR          = 'lightgray';
    $REV_COLOR             = 'lightgreen';
    $OBLIG_COLOR           = 'lightblue';
    $INPUT_BG_COLOR        = 'lightgray';
    $INPUT_COLOR           = 'blue';
    $INPUT_WEIGHT          = 'normal'; // 'bold';
    $MENU_SURROUND_COLOR   = '#302D26';
    $SPINNER_COLOR         = '#4D4B48';
    $HR_COLOR              = 'darkgray';
    $BODY_MARGIN_TOP       = '5px';
?>
```

**arbitrary.php:**

```
    <?php
        error_reporting(-1);
        //ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

        ob_start();
        require_once('definitions.php');
    ?>

    [HTML-Code, CSS and JavaScript file import etc. plus PHP conditions]

    <body style="background-color: <?= $DATA_COLOR ?>; color: <?= $FOREGR_COLOR ?>; margin-top: <?= $BODY_MARGIN_TOP ?>;">

    [more HTML, more PHP]
```

Since all theme - call it so - definitions for the Dark Mode / Night Mode are contained as Variables within the file "definitions.php", I want to enable a user to choose such a theme and save it within her / his own user parameters in a database setting.

Now, as you can see, the first of these color variable definitions is commented out. Only the dark mode is active. I have done this since I only recently added several color schemes to this file.

What I want to do now is to present the user with a button / dropdown option on my PHP GUI from which she / he can choose from several such color schemes in the sense of a theme as explained. Obviously, this does not work with uncommented color schemes. What I have in mind is something like this:

```
    <?php
        if user decides for AliceBlue then
            activate these color variables and save them in her / his user parameters
        elseif user decides for Dark Mode then
            activate those color variables and save them respectively
    ?>
```

Another point to observe is that my system is a multiuser framework with one single application file server containing the entire framework. Thus, there can only be ONE general file "definitions.php".

Is there a way to handle this within the given conditions?

Comment: Look at the last line of what the OP asked for. There can be only 1 file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your existing framework, just save the user's preference `aliceblue` or whatever in the database and/or session variable and then use it to select from an array in `definitions.php`:

```
// Color Composition 02 (#F0F8FF - AliceBlue)
$THEME['aliceblue']['DARK_MODE']     = 0;
$THEME['aliceblue']['SECURITY_MODE'] = 'multi';
//etc...

// Color Composition 03 (#F0F8FF - Night Mode / Dark Mode)
$THEME['nightmode']['DARK_MODE']     = 1;
$THEME['nightmode']['SECURITY_MODE'] = 'single';
//etc...
```

Then assign:

```
$pref          = //users preference
$DARK_MODE     = $THEME[$pref]['DARK_MODE'];
$SECURITY_MODE = $THEME[$pref]['SECURITY_MODE'];
//etc...

//or extract vars from the proper array
extract($THEME[$pref]);
```

Alternately, you could just define them in a switch:

```
$pref = //users preference

switch($pref) {

    // Color Composition 02 (#F0F8FF - AliceBlue)    
    case 'aliceblue':
        $DARK_MODE     = 0;
        $SECURITY_MODE = 'multi';
        //etc...
        break;

    // Color Composition 03 (#F0F8FF - Night Mode / Dark Mode)    
    case 'nightmode':    
        $DARK_MODE     = 1;
        $SECURITY_MODE = 'single';
        //etc...
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a very clever way to handle it. I must confess I always had a "strange relationship" with arrays, but this is the way I will follow. Many thanks again.

Comment: Added another option.

Comment: I have seen it, thank you. "definitions.php" is the very first file loaded. I can assign a default color scheme value for the individual user. But to read it in from the database I need a later file. So, I would encapsulate the assignment as you have described in a file "general.php" which then loads the user's preference and thus in this file assigns the color variables. Then, as a next step I need to load the file "general.php" from all other PHP scripts so as to have the user's choice integrated. Right or do you see another way?

Comment: Using an array just define as shown in definitions.php and then define defaults. 
 Then after you get the user's preference in general.php or another file you can use the `extract($THEME[$pref]);` to define the correct vars that overwrite the default ones.

Comment: One last question:

so as to differentiate in a PHP script beyond first definitions.php and then general.php, can I ask for the darkmode such as this:
`        <?php
            if ($DARK_MODE === 1) {
        ?>
                <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="resources/styles/content_dm.css" />
        <?php
            } elseif ($DARK_MODE === 0) {
        ?>
                <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="resources/styles/content.css" />
        <?php
            }
        ?>`

Comment: Can answer that myself: It works perfectly defining "userPrefence". Now I need to save it into the database and read it in again as my last step.

Answer (score 0):

Make a button which sends an ajax request to itself with one of the parameters the "dark" or "light" theme.
Then in the beginning of the file check which theme the user chose from and save that in a session. 
With a normal if statement check which "theme" the user chose from and load in those values.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will keep it in my focus.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are going the wrong way about this. Using php to dynamically generate themes is a quite bad idea.

First of all, if you are working on a php framework (or any backend framework at all), the code of this framework should not know anything about the UI details. Or you are using the wrong term to describe what you are making.

As for the themes, there are tools for that: you should look into [SASS/SCSS](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables). The UI themes should be handled by the technologies, that are meant for that.

---

If I am guessing correctly, you are confusing thing like "framework" and "cms". Also, I get a feeling that you are still working in the *include oriented* paradigm.

Oh .. and `require` is not a function.

And stop using `?>` at the end of php files: that often cause "header already sent" error.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. The "framework" which I had developed back in 2010 is quite old but has been introduced well into the context of my rather conservative customers. There is nothing to gain for me to introduce posh new techniques since this will not pay off in my customer context. Therefore I have decided long ago to continue to use this "framework" until its very end which is not near at the moment. Therefore, the integration of newer stuff is nice to have for me, but for other projects. AbraCadaver's help was exactly what I needed since it fits in perfectly to the given structure.

Comment: The rest of your advice I have taken on willingly. Thanks again for that.